# Core Data migration: File Exists

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am getting the following error from some users while performing a lightweight Core Data migration on iPhone:

```
{
NSUnderlyingError = Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=17 UserInfo=0x2991d0
"Operation could not be completed. File exists";
destinationURL = file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/AEFD8CE2-0AF6-4227-AB84-73E2F5D83F26/Documents/App.sqlite.new;
reason = "Can't copy source store to destination store path";
sourceURL = file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/AEFD8CE2-0AF6-4227-AB84-73E2F5D83F26/Documents/App.sqlite;
}
```

Is this the result of an interrupted migration? Or some other cause? In any case, is the appropriate remedy to manually delete the .new database before attempting to migrate?

The code is just a simple lightweight migration:

```
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"App.sqlite"]];
NSError *error = nil;
persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
// convert automatically from prior models
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], 
                         NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                         NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                         nil];
if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) 
{
    [MainAppDelegate printDetailedErrors:error];
}
```

UPDATE: BenT from the Apple forums tells me this is a 3.1.x bug, but I haven't yet gone back and verified this with my error log data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Data does not routinely name files `.new`.  Can you show the code that is generating this error?

### update

If the BenT says it is a bug then that is the answer.  If anyone has the answer to a Core Data question, Ben does.

Comment: "Core Data does not routinely name files .new" Yeah, it does, these days. I got the same error, with the same code as @sehugg, during a problematic migration on 10.6.6 (Xcode 3.2.5) -- not iPhone. The relevant application support dictionary shows two versions of the SQL lite store: storedata and storedata.new, with storedata.new reflecting the new version of the data model.

Answer (score 3):

After writing my comment to Marcus S. Zarra's answer, I did some more research and came across [Jerry Krinock's post](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/236685-what-header-has-enum-for-nsposixerrordomain.html) on CocoaBuilder where he realizes that the codes NSPOSIXErrorDomain are really wrapped errors raised by the underlying BSD-layer functions. And according to the [Waikato Linux Users Group](http://www.wlug.org.nz/ErrorMessages) Posix raises error 17 when an attempt is made to overwrite an existing file. 
My conclusion: when something goes wrong in the migration process and you end up with both a  and a .new file in your app's folder in the Application Support directory, you are stuck because everytime that addPersistentStoreWithType: tries to create a store for merging (.new) it runs into Posix error code 17. The solution, after making sure all the settings were correct, was to delete .new and let the migration runs its course. Which it did.